# Setting up a subdomain which points to another IP

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm using Apache, and I'm trying to set up a subdomain for a virtual host, which then points to a server on a different IP address.

So the virtual host is www.example.com, I'd like to set up images.example.com, and point it to 127.0.0.1.

I've consulted some of the answered questions on SO and other sites, but I'm a bit overwhelmed and I don't want to risk wrecking a production site. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would be a better question for http://serverfault.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have control over your DNS entries for this domain, that would be the best and simplest solution- just have www.example.com point to IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and images.example.com point to xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy.  That assumes you have different publicly accessible IP addresses that you can use for the two domains.  And it assumes that you have control over your DNS entries.

If that is not the case, then you may be interested in an answer I posted on another Apache question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319842/1072282

It deals with having one apache server answer for multiple domains on the same IP address, but then sends (proxies) requests for one of the domains to another server to be served there.